# HyperLedger Fabric - How to define signature policy for the channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am a beginner on hyperledger fabric programming. I was wondering where exactly we define the signature policy (SignaturePolicy / ImplicitMetaPolicy) for the network? Is it in some configuration file?

I saw video in below link but I could not understand: ["Signature Policy Sample"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3fwc2LYwKp0)

Can anyone please guide me?

Answer (score 1):

The signature, or endorsement policy is defined when instantiating a chaincode deployed to a given channel using the `-P` switch using the following syntax: `EXPR(E[, E...])` where EXPR is a boolean expression (AND or OR) and E is either a principle or a nested boolean.

For instance, a policy of `AND(Org1.member, Org2.member)` would require that a member of Org1 and Org2 each sign a transaction for it to be validated. A  policy of `AND(Org1.member, OR(Org2.member, Org3.member))` would require a member of Org1 and a member of Org2 or Org3 sign a transaction for it to be validated.

Here's an example chaincode instantiate command:

```
peer chaincode instantiate -C <channelid> -n mycc -P "AND('Org1.member', 'Org2.member')"
```

The documentation can be found in the [Endorsement Policy](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endorsement-policies.html) section of of the Hyperledger Fabric documentation.